# submit form data using ajax in rails 3.2

Tags: jquery, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

my form has two fields name and age i trying to submit via ajax as following

$("#create_taxes").button().click(function(){

```
var valuesToSubmit = $('form').serialize();
alert(valuesToSubmit)
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/taxes.js",  
  data: valuesToSubmit
});
```

});

it returns         `utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=DJ4XLSX%2FK2JPTKJ15SwnTJB6rSIm4uQDallWOJ5FeoE%3D&tax%5Bname%5D=robert` not return age

I also use

```
("#create_ages").button().click(function(){     
  $('form').submit(function(event) {  
    ajax code here  
  });  
)};
```

sorry for my english... Thanks advance

Comment: Why not just add `remote: true` to your `form_for` or `form_tag` call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fine...
$("#create_tax").button().click(function(){

```
 $.ajax({ 
  type: "POST",  
  url: "/taxes.js"  
  data: {tax: { name: $("#name").val(), percentage: $("#percentage").val()} }  
 });
```

});